# Termination of python script while using ZeroMQ with dead server

Tags: python, zeromq, termination, pyzmq

I have a problem in closing python application while I using ZeroMQ.
first I connect to a server that is not running!

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket_id = randomID()
socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, socket_id)
socket.connect("tcp://dead_server")
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
```

and sending my message

```
socket.send(msg)
```

waiting for reply

```
sockets = dict(poller.poll(1000))

if sockets.get(socket) == zmq.POLLIN:
    result = socket.recv()
    print (result)
```

so the server is dead the message will be not send and there is no reply. it is work true. then I close socket and unregister it from poller then connect to alive server with new socket and I send message by the socket and get reply from it.

```
poller.unregister(socket)
socket.close()

socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, socket_id)
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
socket.connect("tcp://alive_server")
socket.send(msg)

sockets = dict(poller.poll(1000))

if sockets.get(socket) == zmq.POLLIN:
    result = socket.recv()
    print (result)

# Every thing ok up to hear
```

after it the application (python script) is not closed (terminate)! it is my problem. [I can close application with `sig_term` but i won't to use it for some reason.]
if I don't send first message to dead server the application is closed truly. I guess the problem is ZeroMQ io thread but I can't solve it.

```
exit(0)    # Not worked
sys.exit(0)    # Not worked
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are encountering ZeroMQ's [LINGER behaviour](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-setsockopt#toc15). LINGER defines how long the Context should wait before allowing `Context.term` to discard messages.  The default in ZeroMQ 2.x is forever, and the default in ZeroMQ 3.x is one second.  If you tell your sockets that they should only linger a short time, your script should exit just fine:

```
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket_id = randomID()
socket.identity = ramdomID()
socket.linger = 250 # 250ms = 1/4 s
socket.connect("tcp://dead_server")
```